# does all the code called after @objc need to be Objective-C compliant?

Tags: ios, swift

When I add a function as a target with #selector to a UIButton, I should mark it as @objc, and that's ok. But the problem is that every function and method that @objc function calls, must be Objective-C compliant, otherwise, app crashes.
For example, when I use Swift enum ( I declared that enum as @objc, too), it crashes with this error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Is it an expected behavior working with @Objc, or I am doing something wrong?

And if it is, is there a workaround or I should make everything called by @objc, objective-C compliant ( in some cases, I need to re-write a big bunch of code)?

Comment: How do you make sure that the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" crash is because of "@objc". If there is any issue with "@objc", the complier won't allow you to run your code and there won't be any runtime error, I believe. So your cash might be in different place or your method name might be mismatches. Also show your code, if possible.

Comment: `@IBAction`. `@objcMembers`.

Comment: This is not expected. You're doing something incorrect. Please create a mcve to demonstrate what you're describing (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code is big, I am trying to reduce it to crash causing parts only.

Answer (score 0):

@objc attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C & Objective-C runtime.

After Swift 4 version launched, Few inference cases of @objc removed. This means in few additional cases where before the @objc header was inferred by the Swift compiler, in Swift 4 not inferred.

So by this cases you can now understand what causes the issue & how to use the @objc.

Make sure you are using swift language version 4 or more updated. From targets -> Build settings find Swift Language version to see what version you are using.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a lot with the code, I noticed that the problem was rising from saving a custom object to UserDefaults, without archiving it using NSKeyedArchiver.